# SQL Joins - Identify the missing lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to find all the rows with a specific tag,that does not have a corresponding line with a different tag.

My Table structure is as follow :

```
Year, Week, Brand, Country, LoactionCode, ProductCategory, VolumeType, Division, Activity, Tag, Qty
```

Some data samples :

```
 2016,1,Dell, USA, 100, Computers, Accessories, Retail, Pricing, 'CF',800
 2016,1,Dell, USA, 100, Computers, Accessories, Retail, Tagging, 'CF',1500
 2016,1,Dell, USA, 100, Computers, Accessories, Retail, Pricing, 'OF',1000
 2016,1,Dell, USA, 100, Computers, Accessories, Retail, Tagging, 'OF',1200
 2016,1,Dell, USA, 100, Computers, Accessories, Retail, Bagging, 'OF',1200
```

I wanted to get the rows which has a tag of 'OF' but do not have corresponding rows with tag 'CF' matching on all the fields "Year, Week, Brand, Country, LoactionCode, ProductCategory, VolumeType, Division, Activity"

Please could some one help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a having clause:

```
SELECT t.year,t.week,t.brand.....t.tag,sum(t.qty?)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.year,t.week,t.brand.....
HAVING count(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'OF' then 1 end) > 0
   AND count(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'CF' then 1 end) = 0
```

I didn't know what you want to do with the qty field when there is more then 1 row with tag = 'OF' , you can change it from sum to max or whatever the requirement.

Comment: select t.tag, count(*) 
from table t
group by t.tag

gives me :

CF 329108
OF 310024

But with the query above , I get the count of difference as only 4056. Ideally it should have been the difference of total number of rows in CF - OF. ( All the rows for the combination is unique)

Comment: @Jinith please update you question with data examples and expected output.

Comment: @Jinith I don't see why this query wouldn't work. Are you sure you don't have duplicates? Use `SELECT t.Tag, t.Year, t.Week, ... FROM theTable t WHERE t.Tag IN ('OF', 'CF') GROUP BY t.Tag, t.Year, t.Week, ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to check.

Comment: @CraigYoung Sorry for the delay.. we have about 60 million lines to validate, so it took a while, and found that there are data issues because of which I wasn't sure if the query works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your sample data to something sensible for testing purposes:

- There are 3 rows with Tag = OF
- One matching CF row
- And one that doesn't match
- Therefore expect 2 rows in the final result set

The query uses a CTE to generate the sample data.
The solution uses a regular query to select the OF rows you *might* be interested in, and EXCEPT followed by a query defining the rows you wish to exclude from the previous result set.

```
;with SampleData AS (
    SELECT  2016 as Year, 1 AS Week, 'Dell' AS Brand, 'CF' AS Tag, 800 AS Qty
    UNION ALL SELECT 2016, 1, 'AMD', 'CF', 1500
    UNION ALL SELECT 2016, 1, 'Intel', 'OF', 1000
    UNION ALL SELECT 2016, 1, 'Apple', 'OF', 1200
    UNION ALL SELECT 2016, 1, 'Dell', 'OF', 1200
)
--Solution uses CTE from above
SELECT  Year, Week, Brand
FROM    SampleData
WHERE   Tag = 'OF'
EXCEPT
SELECT  Year, Week, Brand
FROM    SampleData
WHERE   Tag = 'CF'
```